# display from file using imagick library in php

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, imagick

can you help me please ?

i wrote the following code to display the alphabet images from directory and i run this code through CLI on linux terminal and i get nothing no image displayed ??!!

this is the code:

```
<?php
$name='LUBNA';
$length=  strlen($name);
$name_array=array();
$image_path='/var/www/letters/';

for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {

    $name_array[$i]=$name[$i];

}


    foreach ($name_array as $value) 
    {

        $image = $image_path.$value.'.png';

        $im = new Imagick();

        $im->readImage( $image );


}

?>
```

thanks dears;

Comment: How is it supposed to show image in linux shell? ps: I don't see any `echo` in the code

Comment: i tried to put echo but i get rubbish data not image so please tell me where can i put it or how ??

Comment: I repeat my question: How is it supposed to show image in linux shell?

Comment: sorry but i can`t understand ur question, but i wanna to run my code using CLI, sorry if i don`t understand u but i`m new on php and imagick

Comment: my question is not related to php at all. Have you ever seen any pictures displayed linux shell?

Comment: no i have not, and i know that but i thought that maybe i`m wrong

Comment: so, do you have any questions yet?

Comment: so how and where can i display the images?

Comment: and how can i see the images that i read ??

Comment: at first what do you know about computers?

Comment: OoOps why do u ask such question if u wanna help me, do it without such questions, also i told u i`m new on this world i`m beginner so don`t need to talk like this please...

Comment: I ask that because seems like you don't understand how linux shell works. So you probably need to start with explanation what you want to achieve. What should be the result of your work?

Comment: my work is to display the names using heroglife alphabets which stored as a .png images, i`m new on linux also but i will show u the command that i wrote on terminal to run this code:-

Comment: php -f heroglife_function.php

Comment: I will ask you the same question for the third time: how are you supposed to show image in linux shell? The question is irrelevant to php - how would you do that on linux?

Comment: i can use "display image.png" on the shell to display the image

Comment: So call `display` command in php using `exec`

Comment: i add "shell_exec($im)"
and i get the following---- 
: not found
sh: : not found
: not found
sh: : not found
: not found
sh: : not found
: not found
sh: : not found
: not found
sh: : not found

Comment: Hello just wanna show you the correct code of my question finally i did it :-

Answer (score 0):

Hello just wanna show you the correct code of my question finally i did it :-

```
<?php

$name='lubna';
$name=strtoupper($name);
$length=  strlen($name);
$name_array=array();
$image_path='/var/www/letters/';

$image_array=array();
$image_hight=array();
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {

    $name_array[$i]=$name[$i];
    $image_array[$i]=$image_path.$name[$i].'.png';
    $size=  getimagesize($image_array[$i]);
    $hight=$size[1];
    $image_hight[$i]=$hight;

}

$hight1=  array_sum($image_hight);
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(120, $hight1, new ImagickPixel('none'));
$image->setImageFormat('png');
$offset=0;

  foreach($name_array as $id=>$value) 
   {  

    $img= new Imagick($image_path.$value.'.png');

    $image->compositeimage($img, imagick::COMPOSITE_COPY,0, $offset);

    $offset=$offset+$image_hight[$id];
   }
//header('Content-type: image/png');
//echo $image;
   $image->setImageFormat('png');
   $image->writeimage('/tmp/name.png');
   $cmd1="display /tmp/name.png";
   $run1=  exec($cmd1);

 ?>
```